# How to pass C-style matrix in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, matrix, int

I trying to pass matrix to my function:

```
int movesMatrix[self.map.width][self.map.height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        movesMatrix[x][y] = -1;
    }
}

- (void)foo:(int **)movesMatrix
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            NSLog(@"%d,%d - %d", y, x, movesMatrix[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

But I getting error:BAD_ACCESS
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try to change to following:

```
- (void)foo:(int *)movesMatrix
...
NSLog(@"%d,%d - %d", y, x, movesMatrix[x*self.map.height + y]);
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. But it's not handily. Is there any ability to pass matrix another way?

Comment: @TimurBernikowich to implement your logic you need to define input argument for function as `int movesMatrix[][####]` - instead of ### you **must** put constant value, but currently you have variable `self.map.height`, if you change it to any kind of const - you will be able to use 2d syntax